# Parse URL without DNS queries in Java

Tags: java, url

I'm parsing squid logs with Java. It seemed appropriate to use URL class. This class, however, makes a DNS request, which indefinitely slows down parsing. Are there other easy ways to extract hostname and port from an url?

**Conditions**

- url schema might be ommited in squid logs
- an absent (default) port should be derived for ftp, http, https protocols

Log example:

```
1288763851.129    295 10.10.100.10 TCP_MISS/200 435 GET http://win.mail.ru/cgi-bin/checknew? - DIRECT/217.69.128.52 text/plain
1288763881.110    275 10.10.100.10 TCP_MISS/200 434 GET http://win.mail.ru/cgi-bin/checknew? - DIRECT/217.69.128.52 text/plain
1288763883.093  60001 10.10.102.202 TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT www.update.microsoft.com:443 - DIRECT/- -
1288763884.301      0 10.10.102.202 NONE/400 3506 GET / - NONE/- text/html
1288763911.194    359 10.10.100.10 TCP_MISS/200 435 GET http://win.mail.ru/cgi-bin/checknew? - DIRECT/217.69.128.52 text/plain
1288763941.097    264 10.10.100.10 TCP_MISS/200 434 GET http://win.mail.ru/cgi-bin/checknew? - DIRECT/217.69.128.52 text/plain
1288763944.094  59777 10.10.102.202 TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT www.update.microsoft.com:443 - DIRECT/- -
1288763971.123    289 10.10.100.10 TCP_MISS/200 434 GET http://win.mail.ru/cgi-bin/checknew? - DIRECT/217.69.128.52 text/plain
1288764002.257   1421 10.10.100.10 TCP_MISS/200 435 GET http://win.mail.ru/cgi-bin/checknew? - DIRECT/217.69.128.52 text/plain
```

**EDIT**: I had to write my own class parser for this task. The idea is to use InetAddress if thestring has an IP or simple string for hostnames.

Comment: I wrote [galimatias](https://github.com/smola/galimatias), a Java URL parsing library that you can use for the job. Once it parses the URL, you can get the host and check if it's a domain, a IPv4 or IPv6 address. It's still in early stages but it's quite solid for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Restlet's [`Reference`](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/data/Reference.html) class.

Comment: There is no restlet keyword in my debian distribution. I need more common solution.

Comment: If you program in Java, most libraries won't be bundled out of the box with distributions. If you're after an easy installation, you could consider a build/distribution system such as Maven (Restlet has its own Maven repository, which you could easily configure in your project).

Answer (score 1):

Use the java.net.URI class.

Comment: I'm not surprised. It does parse "https://www.update.microsoft.com:443", which is about the only way you can use that string in Java.

Comment: Do you mean extra quotes are needed?

Comment: I mean a protocol is needed. SO turned that into a link so you can't see what I actually typed.